# Синонім до „рухаюся за напрямком від пункту А до пункту В“

Tags: словосполучення, прийменники

Чи можна вважати такі три словосполучення синонімічними:

1. „рухаюся за напрямком від пункту А до пункту В“;
2. „рухаюся у напрямку від пункту А до пункту В“;
3. „рухаюся вздовж напрямку від пункту А до пункту В“?

Особисто мені фраза „рухаюся у напрямку“ трохи ріже слух. 
Водночас, ми нібито вкладаємо „за напрямком“, „вздовж напрямку“ та „у напрямку“ дещо різний зміст, бо прийменники „за“, „вздовж“ та „у“ мають різне тлумачення.

Comment: Чисто мої відчуття: 1-й варіант вказує на напрямок, але не на кінцеве місце призначення, 2-й (для мене найбільш правильний) вказує, що точка ''В'' і є місцем призначення, а 3-й показує, що ваш шлях частково збігається із напрямком від ''А'' до ''В'', при цьому ні ''А'' ні ''В'' не вказує ні на ваш початок, ні на ваш кінець подорожі.

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо, цікаве розрізнення цих словосполучень. Здається ви маєте рацію. Ваші пояснення істотно залежать від другої половини наведених фраз. Але звідси випливає, що, коли заберемо „від пункту А до пункту В“, то „рухаюся за напрямком“, „рухаюся у напрямку“ та „рухаюся вздовж напрямку“ — синоніми.

Comment: Шчо думајете про [перебувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/perebuvaty)?

Answer (score 1):

Вікіпедія дає нам визначення:

> Сино́німи — це слова однієї частини мови, різні за звучанням і написанням, які мають дуже близьке або тотожне лексичне значення.

Всі наведені вами словосполучення мають близьке значення, що я віддаляюся від пункту А, зближуюся з пунктом В. Отже, так, ці фрази є синонімічними.

*Тепер Соломія вагалась, в якому напрямку йти (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 362)*[[посилання]](http://sum.in.ua/s/naprjamok)

Comment: Як на мене, то питання полягало в тому, яка різниця поміж "у напрямку", "за напрямком" та "вздовж напрямку". За математичною лоґікою ваша відповідь має право на існування, але загалом було б добре, якби ви розширили межі дослідження. До того ж, "вікіпедія" - це не наукове джерело, її може наповнити будь-хто. Було б добре, якби ви користувалися нею як другим чи третім помічним джерелом, а не як основним.

Comment: Так само, як ґуґл - це не зовсім джерело, тому ви дуже доречно його поставили у цій відповіді https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/4551/240 ПІСЛЯ посилання на офіційні джерела.

Comment: @P.Vovk, про всяк випадок зазначу, що в тій відповіді, на яку Ви посилаєтеся, йде відсилка не на результати пошуку в Google, а на «Карти Google» (що, хоч і не найавторитетніше джерело, але здається, наповнюються чи принаймні модеруються працівниками Google, а не просто кожен пише будь-що).

Answer (score 1):

Вживати словосполучення "рух у напрямку" - правильно. Підтвердженням цього є інформація із сайту [ОнлайнКорректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA/):

**Напрямок** — лінія руху або лінія розміщення кого-, чого-небудь; про вектор у просторі.

> Ми йдемо у східному напрямку

Гадаю, що "вздовж напрямку" також можна вживати, адже із його визначення в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/uzdovzh) бачимо:

1. Це слово може вказувати на рух:

> Уживається при вказівці на рух або розміщення кого-, чого-небудь, на
>   спрямованість дії по довжині чогось.

2. Вона також означає: "у напрямку по довжині".

Тобто, "рух у напрямку" та "рух вздовж напрямку" можна вважати синонімами і вони обидва можуть означати переміщеня з пункту А в пункт Б.

А от із "рухом за напрямком" не все так просто, адже в Інтернеті дуже мало випадків вживання цього словосполучення, а також досить часто його плутають із "за напрямом", що згідно до того ж ОнлайнКорректора має зовсім інше значення:

**Напрям** — шлях діяльності, розвитку кого-, чого-небудь; спрямованість якоїсь дії, явища.

> Університет готує фахівців за напрямом «Прикладна лінгвістика».

Тому гадаю, що із вживанням цього словосполучення потрібно бути уважним, і не впевнений, що його можна вважати синонімом до двох попередніх випадків.