# Яка назва вулиці правильна - Нова-Бакинська чи Новобакинська?

Tags: власні-назви, орфографія, прикметники, разом-дефіс-окремо, складні-прикметники

На карті Харкова є дві вулиці, які знаходяться майже поруч – Бакинська і **Новобакинська**. Мене зацікавила розбіжність у написанні назви вулиці у Харкові. На сайтах читаю: "Продаж квартир, м. Харків, вул. Новобакинська".

Але в іншому тексті: "На цій сторінці представлені всі поштові індекси **Ново-Бакинська**, вулиця в місті Харків".

Правопис слова підкреслює Microsoft червоним і подає варіант "**Ново бакинська**" окремо.

Подивилася «Правопис», розділ «Творення прикметників від географічних назв». Дізналася дещо про написання типових прикметників. Новобакинська утворена від сполучення прикметника та іменника «Нова Бакинська». За поданим правилом, треба писати разом.

> Прикметники, утворені від географічних назв, що складаються з прикметника та іменника, пишуться разом: Біла Церква — білоцерківський, Гостра Могила — гостромогильський, Вітряні Гори — вітряногірський, Західна Європа — західноєвропейський.

Про написання через дефіс лише одне правило:

> Прикметники, утворені від географічних назв, написаних через дефіс, пишуться також через дефіс: Пуща-Водиця — пуща-водицький, Михайло-Коцюбинське — михайло-коцюбинський, Камʼянець-Подільський — камʼянець-подільський, Віта-Поштова — віта-поштовий, Київ-Товарний — київ-товарний, Нью-Йорк — нью-йоркський, Ла-Манш — ламаншський.

Вирішила ще почитати інформацію на [сайті Українська мова](http://ukrainskamova.com/)
На цьому сайті детальніше розповідається про творення прикметника, але є приклади, які я не зрозуміла. Гостра Могила — гостромогильський, але Давидів Брід — давидово-брідський.

Допоможіть, любі друзі, визначитись з правильним написанням вулиці.

Answer (score 4):

В офіційному джерелі, на державному сайтах, використовується варіант "вул. Новобакинська", наприклад: ["Додаток до постанови…"](http://kharkivoda.gov.ua/content/documents/763/76284/Attaches/dodatok_do_postanovi_54_okrugi_dlya_publikats.pdf), ["Державний реєстр виборців"](https://www.drv.gov.ua/portal/!cm_core.cm_index?option=ext_dvk&pid100=63&pf5242=631219&prejim=3). Ґуґл-карти також [пропонують](https://goo.gl/J4t2Gr) такий варіант.

Отже, правильно "Новобакинська".